# sony ericsson android doesn't support APK file

Tags: android

i want to try my android application on my phone, so i go to mobile hard disk and make folder called `LMCO3` then run my emulator, then go to `bin` folder on my project folder, i copied the `apk` and put it in the `LMCO3` folder, then i navigate to that folder from my phone and get this message `There are no suppored files in this folder`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason this occurs is because the apk is packaged and not actually installed on your device.

Some of my friends have ran into this problem and what we done to bypass it was to use a free app from Google Play that finds and installs apks found on your device.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.graphilos.apkinst&hl=en

Hope this helps!

Comment: i can't install from that website

Comment: i got this message `you havenn't accessed the Google Play`

Comment: do u mean that i have to access if from my android phone ?

Comment: Yes, access it from your phone.

Comment: @DarrylBayliss i got the same message from my phone

Comment: Don't forget to allow the installation of non-market apps in the system settings. You may also have to take the apk out of the folder

Comment: @DarrylBayliss how can i allow that? sorry i am new to mobile devices :)

Comment: Its cool, not to worry. If you go to settings -> Applications and tick Unknown Sources that should do the trick.

Comment: Take the apk out of the "LMC03" folder and have it in the root and try again with the apk builder. If this doesn't work then the only other thing I can suggest is to download ASTRO file manager on your phone. Does a similar thing to the APK builder except you can navigate your phones folders to find the apk https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en

Comment: i told that i got that message even when i access from mobile

Comment: Ah right, you may need to sign up for an account somehow to access the market to download these apps. If you can do that and try these steps you should be fine.